# "grey" vs "gray" are both common equally in use?

Tags: word-usage, spelling, transatlantic-differences

Yesterday I wrote "**gray**" in the meaning of the color, but my friend corrected me and told me to write "**grey**". Today I checked in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gray?q=GRAY) and *I found that they are both correct for the same meaning*. So, now I just have doubt which one of them is more common in use.

Comment: I a native speaker of American English and I've used *grey* and *gray* interchangeablly all my life, without care for which one is the more common. I've never before heard that one of them is supposed to be used in the UK.

Comment: Although see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5390/which-is-the-correct-spelling-grey-or-gray and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255435/gray-or-grey-which-one-should-i-use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, they are both correct. Which one is better depends on who you ask. In the USA, it's spelled "**gray**"¹ and in the UK, it's spelled "**grey**". A fun mnemonic for this is **A** for America, **E** for England. Plenty of other words do this also. Color/colour, fiber/fibre, liter/litre, etc.

The population of the USA is higher so gray is technically more common. Use the one that matches the country you're in and the people you're writing for.

If you're in neither country, it doesn't really matter which one you use. Pick one you like and stick with it.

---

¹ *To be fair, I'm from the USA, and I find myself frequently writing "grey" by accident sometimes. It's certainly not a hard and fast rule, and you could likely get away with either one.*

Comment: @AlanCarmack Check out these Google Ngrams: [American](http://bit.ly/1UNwr1e) and [british](http://bit.ly/22wR1cp). Also, pretty much every link I can find on Google when I search [gray vs grey](http://bit.ly/22GGmIS) says the same thing. Sure, using grey in AME, or gray in BRE isn't *wrong* per se, but it's clearly less common.

Comment: Yeah, I've upvoted your answer, although to me the UK/US difference is not as regularized as that of the other examples you provide. Maybe as a kid I picked up *grey* somewhere.

Comment: Remember HTML color names, Version 7 and earlier of IE only accepted gr**a**y for #080808, and only lightgr**e**y for #D3D3D3.